# Symfony convert native sql to query-builder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony

I have an sql query:

```
SELECT users.username, count(follows.user_id)
FROM follows
INNER JOIN users ON follows.follow_user_id=users.id
GROUP BY follow_user_id;
```

In Sonata Admin, I want to filter my data with the number of followers. 
The request works, but I can't use it in Sonata Admin.

I have the function:

```
public function callbackFilterFollow($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value)
{
    if (!$value) {
        return;
    }
    //$queryBuilder->select('username')->addGroupBy('o.id');
    return true;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to use the query-builder to convert my SQL query.

Comment: What did you try so far ? How does your current query-builder look like?

Comment: I try to build my query step by step. For the moment i have         $queryBuilder->from('follows', 'f')->select('COUNT(f.user_id)');
 but Symfony say follows class is not defined. Follows is'nt an entity .

Comment: I try:         $queryBuilder->innerJoin('o.followings', 'f')->andWhere('user_id = :id')->setParameter('id', 1);
 but doesn't work ><'

Answer (score 0):

Have you mapped your query tables to entities?
If not take a look at the doctrine [documentation for oneToMany relationships](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional).

Once you have done that you can do something like this, keep in mind to use your object fields and not like below the table field names!!

```
$qb->select('u.username, COUNT(f.user_id) as cnt')
        ->from('UserBundle:Follows' , 'f') //this is your entity
        ->leftJoin('UserBundle:Users','u') //your users entity
        ->groupBy('f.follow_user_id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Your entities might need to have the full path. There are however two things that I don't get about what you are doing.

1. You are counting for an inner join, if you just SELECT COUNT(*) with the inner join you don't need the group by.
2. You are creating a sonata filter but I don't see where you use a parameter, I assume your real query looks the different and has the value as a parameter somewhere.
   So you might need some changes, you can find more info [on this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656681/doctrine-2-select-count-groupby/26656831).