# Doctrine 2 select count groupBy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to retrieve a number of rows with unique uids.

```
$qb->select('COUNT() as cnt')
            ->from($type, 'c')
            ->groupBy('c.organization, c.process_role, c.domain, c.year')
            ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult()
```

But it returns an array of group counts. How should I write this correct?

Finally, that works, but it's kinda ugly

```
$count = $this->_em->createQuery( 'SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM '.$type.' as c WHERE c.id IN ('
            . 'SELECT c1.id FROM ' . $type . ' c1 '
            . 'GROUP BY c1.organization, c1.process_role, c1.domain, c1.year)')
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try breaking up your single `groupBy` into `addGroupBy` functions:

```
$qb->select('COUNT(c) as cnt')
            ->from($type, 'c')
            ->groupBy('c.organization')
            ->addGroupBy('c.process_role')
            ->addGroupBy('c.domain')
            ->addGroupBy('c.year')
            ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

However this does in fact return the same thing since it will just group results into unique sets by those 4 variables. You should instead use a `DISTINCT` selection method and count the resulting rows.

```
$rows = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT DISTINCT c.organization, c.process_role, c.domain, c.year FROM ' . $type . ' c'
    )
    ->getArrayResult();
$count = count($rows);
```

This is the only known method to me that will work since DQL won't support any alternative strategies (such as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ... )`)

Comment: Unfortunately, it leads to an error - Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ',' 

Select distinct allows only one parameter.

Comment: @Kamil Let's try some straight DQL instead. See my edit. Note that I wouldn't use `$type` concatenated like that if it was an unsafe variable.

Comment: @Kamil I've tested all my attempts and condensed it into my only known correct result. Give it a shot.

Comment: That throws this exeption:  line 0, col 23 near '(SELECT DISTINCT': Error: Class '(' is not defined.   +
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT COUNT(cnt) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.organization, c.process_role, c.domain, c.year FROM TSO\Bundle\Entity\Capacity c) cnt

And another one above with get single scalar result also throws an exeption on multiple count parameters

Comment: Finally, that works, but it's kinda ugly

    $count = $this->_em->createQuery( 'SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM '.$type.' as c WHERE c.id IN ('
                . 'SELECT c1.id FROM ' . $type . ' c1 '
                . 'GROUP BY c1.organization, c1.process_role, c1.domain, c1.year)')
                ->getSingleScalarResult();

Comment: Yeah compared to that I think you'd be better off just using a PHP `count` method like the one in my example. Best of luck!

Comment: The problem is about I try to avoid a php count in order to improve executioin time.((
Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

Insted of `$qb->select();` use `$qb->distinct();`.  I hope it works.

Comment: `distinct()` is [a function that is used as a flag, not a selector](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html#_distinct). Its usage is also not documented so I'd be unsure of its results.